# jquery remote validation is not submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I cannot get this basic form validation to submit. I read that the remote is the cause. Is there any way to fix it as I need it to check if a username exists before registering a new user?

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin v1.12.0 if it matters

```
$("#regForm").validate({
   rules: {
        username: {         
            remote: {   
                url: "username_db.php", 
                type: "post"     
            }   
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {         
            remote: "Username already in use"
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
require_once 'db.php';

if ( $conn = connect() ) {
    $row = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."'");
    $row->execute();
    $rs = $row->rowCount();

    if($rs > 0){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="regForm" name="regForm">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO">          
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things;

First: You must protect yourself against SQL injection - see for example [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Second: Your php must *output* the 'true' or 'false' value, not return it. According to the [remote-method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) documentation, it could also output a json-encoded error message like `"The user does not exist"`

Third: You can use the [error_log()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to debug your PHP code and ensure that it's running - the messages appear in the php log file.

So try this for your PHP code:

```
require_once 'db.php';

//(Using PDO for db access - see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php )
if ($pdo = connect() ) { 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindValue(":username", $_REQUEST['username']);
    if ( $stmt->fetchAll() ) 
        echo "true";
    else 
        echo json_encode("User does not exist");
}
```

Comment: I had this before with echo's and it didn't work. But tried your way too and no luck either

Comment: Some other things to check;
1. Open the developer console (press F12) and check that the HTTP request is being sent, and that it contains the expected values.
2. Put `error_log( var_export($_REQUEST, true) );` in your php file, to check that it's getting the expected parameter.

Comment: this didn't return anything, I am not sure why as I remember this working in the past and suddenly it stopped

Comment: What didn't return anything? In order, A: Is your client sending a request? (Look at the developer console in your browser) B: Is your server receiving the request? (Look in the apache access log) C: Is your program running? (Have it `echo` out something and `exit`, and try visiting the URL manually)

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not specified what the exact problem is, you are not sending back any values to the `validate` plugin.

The plugin expects something that evaluates to valid json and although you have a `return` statement, you are not actually outputting anything.

The end of your php script should be something like:

```
if($rs > 0){
    echo json_encode(false);    // returns "false"
}else{
    echo json_encode(true);     // returns "true"
}
```

Also, the reason you prepare a statement, is to protect yourself from sql injection. You would need a placeholder and bind the value of your variable after preparing.

Comment: this didn't work. i had echo 'true' and 'false' before I changed it for testing..

Comment: @Gadgetster What does your form look like?

Comment: @Gadgetster Is the name attribute really like that or is that just a typo here?